# Comparing Decimal Values Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, decimal

I am trying to compare decimal values in Excel VBA and delete rows that 
match the criteria. This was my original code and it skipped over many rows.

```
For Each i In WSData.Range("A7", WSData.Range("A7").End(xlDown)).Cells
     If i.Offset(0, 3).Value >= 98 Then
        i.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

And the values on the spreadsheet are decimal values just with the % sign.

[image]

I tried "> 97.99" because Excel has some issues with floating point comparison but it still doesn't accurately compare.

Here is what it shows after using Selection.Value.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You must then have a custom mask on the numbers.  Something like `00.00"%"` which means the numbers are not true percentages but number mascarading as percentages.

Comment: No. These are values in the hundreds. I changed back to >= 98.00 and it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Percentages are decimal depicted with integers. For example 100.00% is stored as 1 and 98.01% is stored as .9801.

Therefor you need to adjust the threshold:

```
For Each i In WSData.Range("A7", WSData.Range("A7").End(xlDown)).Cells
     If i.Offset(0, 3).Value >= .98 Then
        i.EntireRow.Delete
     End If
Next
```

The second problem is that when deleting rows it is best to iterate backwards.  Otherwise it might miss some rows, because as each row is deleted it is moved up and then the next iteration skips the next row.

Change i from a range to a long and use this:

```
For  i = WSData.Range("A7").End(xlDown).row to 7 Step -1
     If WSData.Cells(i,3).Value >= .98 Then
        Row(i).Delete
     End If
Next
```

Edit: Because it appears there is a custom mask on the number format that is forcing numbers to look like percentages try this:

```
For  i = WSData.Range("A7").End(xlDown).row to 7 Step -1
     If WSData.Cells(i,3).Value >= 98 Then
        Row(i).Delete
     End If
Next
```

If this works then your main problem was that you were looking at column D.  The offset is additive.  So when you used `.offset(0,3)` it was moving three columns from column A. 1 + 3 is 4.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @tigeravatar

Comment: @Dombey If you are deleting rows, you need to work from the bottom of the range up, else your algorithm won't work.  If you are doing that, and still deleting 24.75%, etc, then there is something flakey about your data.

Comment: @Dombey Then you have a mixture of numbers and text that look like numbers.

Comment: @Dombey a quick check would be to select one of the cells, then in the immediate window in the VBE type `? Selection.Value` and hit enter.  If it returns `24.75%` then it is a text, if it returns `0.2475` then it is a number.

Comment: @Dombey One more question, are the percentages in column D?

Comment: @Dombey whew... that took a while, glad to finally resolve the problem.  Thanks for your patience.